# Getting original date from java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) and extracting Month

Tags: java, android, datetime

I am using `Calendar.getInstance().getTime()` to get current date and time in android, additionally following a response is saw on Stackoverflow I am using `java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format()` to get the string representation of the date I generated earlier and store it in a table. However how can I convert from the string representation back to the `Calendar` format it came from, and how can I extract the month from there? Please I have tried `SimpleDateFormat` and it asks me to place suppress warnings all over the place and brings errors. Please any help or better advice or guidance will be greatly appreciated, thxs.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you an idea about how to work with calendar, how to format and parse a date:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

Date currentDate = calendar.getTime();
String formattedDate = sdf.format(currentDate);

Date reParsedDate = sdf.parse(formattedDate);
calendar.setTime(reParsedDate);
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

---

**Nevertheless it would be better to keep your date object in some variable instead of reparsing it from the formatted string!**

Comment: Thnx @JDC,but with SimpleDateFormat it is asking me to Cast "calendar.getTime()" and "sdf.parse(formattedDate);" to Date.The other requirement link add throw exception show up with other errors.what other option can u recommend?

Comment: Beware that the month you get from a `Calendar` object is 0-based: 0 for January through 11 for December. Just add 1 if you want a usual 1-based month number.

Comment: @user3015410 There should be no need of casting as the method already returns a value of type `Date` (see: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime() ). Are you sure you are using `java.util.Date` and not `java.sql.Date` ? Regarding the Exception on the `parse()` method: you will ave to handle it using try/catch or bubble it up by adding it to the method signature. This exception occurs if the passed `String` can not be parsed because it has some other format as the pattern specified in the formatter.

Comment: Thnxs @JDC, however Date in your code snippet shows as java.sql.Date. What can i do pls

Comment: Ok i discovered that i was using  java.sql.Date instead of java.util.Date. Refactor code in progree.....